# How to connect Flutter web debug session from Chrome on iOS?

Tags: flutter

I want to get access to a debug session on a Flutter web app running on an iOS device.

I was able to get the app running on the device on Chrome using

`flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080 --web-hostname 0.0.0.0`.

However, I can't access the debug session to be able to fix bugs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.